# What is wrong with this string palindrome program?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++17, palindrome

**THIS PROBLEM IS SOLVED**
**Given a string, determine if it is a palindrome, considering only alphanumeric characters and ignoring cases.**

```
int Solution::isPalindrome(string A) {
    vector<int> v1,v2;
    int size = A.size(),a;
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
        if(isalpha(A[i]) || isdigit(A[i]))
        {   
             a = (int)A[i];
           
            v1.push_back(a);
        }
        if(isalpha(A[size-1-i]) || isdigit(A[size-1-i]))
        {     
             a = (int)A[size-1-i];
        
            v2.push_back(a);
        }
        
    }
    if(v1==v2)
    return 1;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Tagging with all these C++ variants serves no purpose here. If you are using a particular standard tag with that. C++17 implies 14, 11, etc.

Comment: Tip: Pass in strings as `const string&` to avoid making excess copies.

Comment: Is `std::reverse` off limits here?

Comment: _"What is wrong with this string palindrome program?"_ — How do you know that anything is wrong? This is what you should have told us in the first place.

Comment: it can be a character or the an integer, so integer needs no typecasting, but a character does here.

Comment: @MayurAgarwal: I don't think `(int)x` does what you think it does.

Comment: (int)alphabet = ASCII code of alphabet

Comment: you're right there. I got a little bit confused. I forgot I am using a string

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't ignore cases, because the comparison `v1 == v2` is done with the same case as the original string.

Change

```
v1.push_back(a);
```

to

```
v1.push_back(tolower(a));
```

And similarly for `v2`.

Honestly just five minutes testing should have told you this, it's not a hard bug to find.

**EDIT**

Since I answered this question the code has been changed, to something that no longer compiles. I really don't feel inclined to answer ever changing questions.

**EDIT**

Well it's changed again. At least it compiles now.

Comment: You're right! ;) I didn't actually read the question carefully.

Comment: I had written the program somewhere else, and I copied the wrong version to put it here in the question. There was a minor mistake.

Comment: @MayurAgarwal Well the problem I described above is still there. Plus your original version was better than the current version. I would go back to the original version, and then apply the solution I give above and see how you do.

Comment: I have just declared 'a', in the starting, and the added the condition if the A[i] will be an integer.

Comment: @MayurAgarwal A char can convert to an integer automatically you don't need to use a cast and an extra variable. It also does nothing to address the problem I identified.